# Finding a derivative from an integral $\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function, and for $x \neq 0$, define the function $F$ as follows:

$$F(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt,$$

while we define $F(0) = f(0)$.  Use the definition of derivative to find $F'(0)$.

I'm really stuck on what to do here. I'm not given a function for $f$ to use in the standard derivative definitions, and we can't use $x$ at $0$.

Any advice, or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that's exactly what the teacher had in mind — assuming you saw the theorem on change of variables — but a rather common approach to deal with this sort of parameterized integral is a change of variable of the form $u=t/x$: you'll get
$$
F(x) = \int_{0}^1 f(xu) du
$$
which is simpler to deal with.

Comment: And how this trick helps to find the limit?

Comment: By noting that $$\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x} = \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(xu)-f(0)}{xu}u du$$ and then taking the limit as $x\to 0^+$, interverting limit and integral.

Comment: Then you need to justify exchange of $\lim$ and $\int$

Comment: Yes. On an interval, it's not really a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
F'(0)
=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}
=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{-1}\int_0^x f(t)dt-f(0)}{x}
$$
Now apply L'Hopitale's rule and do not forget fundamental theorem of calculus.